# Adding a column to a csv file with paste in cygwin

Tags: bash, csv, cygwin, paste

I'm working with csv files in **cygwin**, trying to use correctly the
command paste to no avail. This is an example of what I get when trying to
paste the files tmp1 and tmp2:

```
$ cat tmp1
inst,actual,predic,pfraud,plegit
1,0,0,0.298,0.702
2,0,0,0.052,0.948
3,0,1,0.535,0.465
4,0,0,0.157,0.843
5,0,0,0.002,0.998
6,0,0,0.399,0.601
7,0,0,0.325,0.675
8,0,0,0.09,0.91
9,0,0,0.08,0.92

$ cat tmp2
AMOUNT
0.882342
1.032142
0.89484
0.862725
1.001504
1.360017
1.323887
1.287036
1.199779

$ paste -d, tmp1 tmp2
,AMOUNTtual,predic,pfraud,plegit
,0.88234298,0.702
,1.03214252,0.948
,0.89484535,0.465
,0.86272557,0.843
,1.00150402,0.998
,1.36001799,0.601
,1.32388725,0.675
,1.2870369,0.91
,1.1997798,0.92
```

The desired outcome should be:

```
inst,actual,predic,pfraud,plegit,AMOUNT
1,0,0,0.298,0.702,0.882342
2,0,0,0.052,0.948,1.032142
3,0,1,0.535,0.465,0.89484
4,0,0,0.157,0.843,0.862725
5,0,0,0.002,0.998,1.001504
6,0,0,0.399,0.601,1.360017
7,0,0,0.325,0.675,1.323887
8,0,0,0.09,0.91,1.287036
9,0,0,0.08,0.92,1.199779
```

Anyone knows what's going on here?

thnx!

**Update**: emphasis added to the fact that it is in cygwin that this happens, not on a Linux machine.

**Update 2**: I already tried with other variants, like `paste -d"," tmp1 tmp2`, `paste -d',' tmp1 tmp2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the answer was really simple, and was given in the comment of @shellter.

Simply changing the formats of the files with `dos2unix` fixed the problem (in fact, just changing tmp1 did the trick). It seems that without this fix, `paste` doesn't quite get where each line of tmp1 ends, resulting in what I posted originally.

So, to fix this and any possible subsequent problem I just `dos2unix`ed every file:

```
dos2unix tmp*
paste -d, tmp1 tmp2 > new_file.csv
```

Hope this saves someone's time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note about what happened in your case: Windows line endings consists of characters `\r\n`, whereas Linux ones of `\n` only. `\n` (10) is *LF* which means *line feed*. `\r` (13) is CR - *carriage return*. Naming of that characters explains why your result looks as it looks.

`paste` took characters from the 1st line in the 1st file. Line ended with `\r\n`. That means `\r` moved "cursor" to the beginning of line and `\n` told `paste` to switch to the 2nd file. Because "cursor" was now on the beginning of the line instead of on the end, characters from the 2nd file overwrote previous characters.

So `paste` recognized well where each line ends, it just also interpreted the character *CR*.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

`paste -d "," tmp1 tmp2`

This works without quotes on the comma as well.

The result:

```
inst,actual,predic,pfraud,plegit,AMOUNT
1,0,0,0.298,0.702,0.882342
2,0,0,0.052,0.948,1.032142
3,0,1,0.535,0.465,0.89484
4,0,0,0.157,0.843,0.862725
5,0,0,0.002,0.998,1.001504
6,0,0,0.399,0.601,1.360017
7,0,0,0.325,0.675,1.323887
8,0,0,0.09,0.91,1.287036
9,0,0,0.08,0.92,1.199779
```

Comment: Yes, this and my original attempt both work in a normal Linux machine, but doesn't seem to work on cygwin (I should've emphasized that more I think...).